# How do I set a "property" of a HOC?

Tags: reactjs

How do I set a "property" as listed in this table:

https://reactjsexample.com/a-set-of-higher-order-components-to-turn-any-list-into-an-animated-sortable-list/

Comment: Please elaborate the issue which specific property you want to set.

Comment: set "axis" to 'x'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This needs to go here in `SortableList`

```
<SortableList items={this.state.items} axis="x" onSortEnd={this.onSortEnd} />
```

Working demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-eqxyqy

Comment: The items are not horizontal?